# Print unknown size of array

Tags: arrays, memory, struct, size, realloc

Good afternoon/evening peeps. I have another noob question for yall. Say I have the following struct.

```
typedef struct my_example{
 int student_id;
}example;
```

Then I created the following function

```
void addStuff(example *info) 
{
 int i, loop=0;
 printf("Enter Number of Students: ");
 scanf("%d", &loop);

 info=realloc(info, sizeof(int)*loop);

 for(i=0; i<loop; i++)
 {
  printf("Enter Student ID: ");
  scanf("%d", &info[i].student_id);
 }
}
```

I know there are various ways to print this out, for example I could use a counter and use that counter to loop and print out the information that I want. But, is there a way to print out the information in my function without using a counter?

When I was learning about files, I was able to scanf whatever document until it reached EOF. Thus you can count every character and store it in a value that I could call length_of_array. However I couldn't figure out how to print out the necessary information I want from my example. I tried:

```
while(info[i].student_id != 0)
{
 printf("%d", info[i].student_id);
 i++;
}
```

My program was shooting blanks though. My goal from this exercise is to learn these things.

Memory management, I want to be able to continue to add students and regardless the size of the array I want to be able to print it out without using a counter, knowing how to this now would improve my programming skills. But as a newbie to programming, anyones help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: value of `info[i].student_id` equal to zero, does not guarantee end of your array (unless you used `calloc` but as we see, your array was filled completely, so there's no zero-room left, to check end of array )

Comment: Create a linked list.

Comment: : ) Or allocate one byte more than needed, and use that extra byte to indicate end of buffer (just like EOF does in files)

Comment: Mangusta how would I go on and do that? If im using realoc to allocate my function dynamically?